# Change all tweak-tool config files for all users

Tags: debian, gnome3

To be able to access the Minimize and Maximize buttons in Debian, I have to change every users settings from gnome-tweak-tool, individually. Is there a way for me to change every users tweak-tool setting's so that they are all the same, without doing it individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Created a user called "tmpuser"

Logged in as that user in GUI mode and apply the following tweaks:

- Enabled Desktop icons (done by launching Tweak tool, and setting “Icons on Desktop” in “Desktop” tab)
- Enabled maximize and minimize buttons on window title bars (done by launching Tweak tool, and setting “Maximize” and “Minimize” in “Windows” tab)
- Enabled a Gnome extension to modify Alt+Tab behavior and not group windows by application (done by launching Tweak tool, and setting 
  “Alternatetab” in “Extensions” tab)
- Created a keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+T to launch a terminal window
  Set the default applications under All Settings > Details > Default

Added the following launchers on the favorites bar:

- Tweak tool
- Firefox
- LibreOffice Writer / Calc
- VLC
- File manager
- Terminal
- Help
- Simple scan

Applications as follows:

- Web -> Firefox
- Mail -> Icedove
- Calendar -> Icedove
- Music -> VLC
- Video -> VLC
- Photos -> Image viewer

Logged out of the newly created user, and then:

```
rm -rf /etc/skel/*
cp -ra /home/tmpuser/ /etc/skel
chown -R root:root /etc/skel
# Double checked that all permissions of /etc/skel and its contents are as prior to replacing the folder (755 root:root for folders, 644 root:root for files)
rmdir /etc/skel/Documents/
rmdir /etc/skel/Downloads/
rmdir /etc/skel/Templates/
rmdir /etc/skel/Videos/
rmdir /etc/skel/Desktop/
rmdir /etc/skel/Music/
rmdir /etc/skel/Pictures/
rmdir /etc/skel/Public/
rm /etc/skel/.Xauthority
rm /etc/skel/.xsession-errors
rm -rf /etc/skel/.ssh/
rm -rf /etc/skel/.cache/
```

- Removed the tmpuser

Re-created some of the deleted folders, as otherwise Gnome failed to create them automatically (even though they were originally not there in /etc/skel, but presumably due to the presence of the new config, Gnome thinks that they are already there)

```
mkdir /etc/skel/Documents/ /etc/skel/Downloads/ /etc/skel/Templates/ /etc/skel/Videos/ /etc/skel/Music/ /etc/skel/Pictures/ /etc/skel/Public/
```

And, applied the same tweaks to the existing users:

```
for i in `ls /home`; do su $i -c "echo $i"; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo ok; cp -r /etc/skel /home/$i/; cp -r /home/$i/skel/.* /home/$i/; rm -r /home/$i/skel; fi; done
```